# SQL Query with Recursive Nature

Tags: sql, dremio

Suppose I have a table with 2 columns: **PURCHASE_DATE** and **ACCOUNT_NUMBER**:

| PURCHASE_DATE | ACOUNT_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 123 |
| 2022-01-01 | 233 |
| 2022-01-01 | 333 |
| 2022-01-02 | 433 |
| 2022-01-02 | 233 |
| 2022-01-02 | 333 |
| 2022-01-03 | 123 |
| 2022-01-03 | 233 |
| 2022-01-03 | 335 |

I want to choose 1 account per day to send him a promotional SMS. (for example, first account when ordered by ACCOUNT_NUMBER). But on the second day, if the first account is the one to who I already sent an SMS the previous day, I need to exclude him/her and choose the next one. On the third day, I should exclude 2 accounts selected during the last 2 days, and so on.

Desired Output:

| PURCHASE_DATETIME | ACOUNT_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 123 |
| 2022-01-02 | 233 |
| 2022-01-03 | 335 |

As you can see, on 2022-01-03 accounts 123 and 233 were excluded.

I have to tackle this problem in **Dremio** where, as I know, we can only create views and we can't create temporary tables or Recursive CTEs.

I need to automate this process if possible. How would you approach this kind of problem?

Comment: A good way to solve this problem is to create a new table, maybe called `sms_sent_log`. In each row put the account number and the date for each SMS you send. Then use it to exclude accounts from consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, as I've mentioned, we can't automate the table creation process. I mean, we can't create `sms_sent_log` and then use it in the same query. We only have VIEWs.

Answer (score 0):

In dremio you can create tables using CTE the use it in others query, you don't need automate the creation of tables, you can do both with query SQL
Reference: https://docs.dremio.com/software/sql-reference/sql-commands/with/